# concatenate 2 lines in one line using unix command

Tags: unix

I would like to concatenate 2 lines in one. Let's say I have a data like these,

```
PK26338
565
PK27876
574
PK13472
546
PK03604
540
```

Want to have a format like these with tab delimited.

```
PK26338    565
PK27876    574
PK13472    546
PK03604    540
```

What will be the most efficient way using unix command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is easiest and most efficient in this case:

```
paste -d '\t' - - < file
```

- `-d '\t'` tells `paste` to join input lines using a `\t` (tab) character
- `- -` tells `paste` to read *pairs* of input lines from stdin (`-` is by convention used to represent stdin in lieu of a filename).
- `< file` sends the input file `file` to `paste` via stdin (the standard input).

In effect, the command reads *pairs* of lines from `file` and joins the lines of each pair, separated with a tab, to form a single output line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/^PK/) {chomp; print "$_\t"}else{print}' file
PK26338    565
PK27876    574
PK13472    546
PK03604    540
```